# Flutter: Having a problem with Custom Drawer and internal navigation on fab pressed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-provider

I am trying to build a custom drawer, just to practice while I study flutter and collecting ideas from videos I see on the web.

In the app I am trying to make, I use Provider and Navigator 2.0 (Router) and it has been not easy so far to implement Navigator 2.

The as mentioned is made as a Stack that has as children the DrawerComponent and the Specific page handled by a DrawerManager and an AppRouter.

In the main page I have a Floating Action Button that on pressed does an effect transitioning from the list of Todos to the AddTodo Screen like a circle from the bottom corner revealing the new page.

like this image shows

[image]

The problem is basically that whenever I press the FAB the animation works, but I do not want to see the Drawer in full page like that is the page from where I am transitioning. Instead I would like to see a transition from the TodoList page to the AddTodo Page.

Here the code:

```dart
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  final _drawerManager = DrawerManager();
  late AppRouter _appRouter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _appRouter = AppRouter(drawerManager: _drawerManager);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => _drawerManager),
        Provider<ITodoRepository>(
          lazy: false,
          create: (_) =>
              TodoRepository(db: Provider.of<HeyTaskDatabase>(context)),
        )
      ],
      child: Consumer<DrawerManager>(
        builder: (context, drawerManager, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
              home: Scaffold(
                  backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 2, 9, 38),
                  body: Stack(children: [
                    const DrawerComponent(),
                    WillPopScope(
                      onWillPop: () async {
                        if (drawerManager.isDrawerOpen) {
                          drawerManager.closeDrawer();
                          return false;
                        } else {
                          return true;
                        }
                      },
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          drawerManager.closeDrawer();
                        },
                        onHorizontalDragStart: (details) =>
                            drawerManager.setDragging(true),
                        onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
                          if (!drawerManager.isDragging) return;
                          const minMove = 1;
                          if (details.delta.dx > minMove) {
                            drawerManager.openDrawer();
                          } else if (details.delta.dx < -minMove) {
                            drawerManager.closeDrawer();
                          }
                          drawerManager.setDragging(false);
                        },
                        child: AnimatedContainer(
                            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                            transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                                drawerManager.xOffSet, drawerManager.yOffSet, 0)
                              ..scale(drawerManager.scaleFactor),
                            child: AbsorbPointer(
                              absorbing: drawerManager.isDrawerOpen,
                              child: ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                    drawerManager.isDrawerOpen ? 20 : 0),
                                child: Router(
                                  routerDelegate: _appRouter,
                                  backButtonDispatcher:
                                      RootBackButtonDispatcher(),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )),
                      ),
                    )
                  ])));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then the TodoScreen:

```dart
class _TodoRoosterScreenState extends State<TodoRoosterScreen>  {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Consumer<DrawerManager>(
        builder: (context, drawerManager, child) {
          return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: LightColors.backgroundColor,
            appBar: AppBar(
              elevation: 0.0,
              backgroundColor: LightColors.backgroundColor,
              leading: DrawerMenuComponent(
                onClick: () {
                  Provider.of<DrawerManager>(context, listen: false)
                      .openDrawer();
                },
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                  color: Colors.black38,
                )
              ],
              title: const Text(""),
            ),
            body: _buildTodoList(context),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: LightColors.iconBlue,
              onPressed: () async {
                Provider.of<DrawerManager>(context, listen: false).goTo(AvailablePages.addTodo);
                },
              child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
          );
        },
      );

  Widget _buildTodoList(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<Todo>>(
      stream: Provider.of<ITodoRepository>(context, listen: false).watchTodos(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Todo>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final todos = snapshot.data ?? [];
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: todos.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final todo = todos[index];
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0, left: 16.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 70,
                  child: _buildSlidable(context, todo),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        } else if(snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
        }
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
        }
    );
  }


-----
```

And the add todo one:

```dart
class AddTodoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTodoScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static MaterialPage page() {
    return MaterialPage(
        name: HeyTaskPages.addTodoPath,
        key: ValueKey(HeyTaskPages.addTodoPath),
        child: const AddTodoScreen());
  }

  @override
  _AddTodoScreenState createState() => _AddTodoScreenState();
}

class _AddTodoScreenState extends State<AddTodoScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller =
        AnimationController(
            vsync: this,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
            upperBound:1.3);
     _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller,
      builder: (context, child){
        return ClipPath(
          clipper:AddTaskClipper(value: _controller.value),
          child:child ,
        );
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children:  const [
              Text("Add Todo Screen"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: LightColors.iconBlue,
            onPressed: () async {
              //Provider.of<ITodoRepository>(context, listen: false).insertTodo(todo)
              _controller.reverse().then((value) => Provider.of<DrawerManager>(context, listen: false).goTo(AvailablePages.todoRooster));
            },
            child: const Icon(Icons.done),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddTaskClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final double value;

  AddTaskClipper({required this.value});

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.addOval(Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(size.width, size.height), radius: value *size.height));
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

The APPRouter

```dart
class AppRouter extends RouterDelegate
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin {

  @override
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;
  final DrawerManager drawerManager;


  AppRouter({
    required this.drawerManager,
  }) : navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>() {
    drawerManager.addListener(notifyListeners);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    drawerManager.addListener(notifyListeners);
    super.dispose();
  }

  // 5
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      transitionDelegate: NoAnimationTransitionDelegate(),
      key: navigatorKey,
      onPopPage: _handlePopPage,
      pages: [
        if(drawerManager.selectedPage == AvailablePages.todoRooster) TodoRoosterScreen.page(openDrawer: drawerManager.openDrawer),
        if(drawerManager.selectedPage == AvailablePages.categories) CategoriesScreen.page(openDrawer: drawerManager.openDrawer),
        if(drawerManager.selectedPage == AvailablePages.settings) SettingsScreen.page(openDrawer: drawerManager.openDrawer),
        if(drawerManager.selectedPage == AvailablePages.addTodo) AddTodoScreen.page(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

The drawer manager:

```dart
class DrawerManager extends ChangeNotifier{

  AvailablePages selectedPage = AvailablePages.todoRooster;

  void goTo(AvailablePages page){
    if(selectedPage == page) {
      closeDrawer();
      return;
    }
    closeDrawer();
    selectedPage = page;
  }

  double xOffSet = 0;
  double yOffSet = 0;
  double scaleFactor = 1;
  bool isDrawerOpen = false;
  bool isDragging = false;

  void openDrawer() {
    xOffSet = 230;
    yOffSet = 100;
    scaleFactor = 0.8;
    isDrawerOpen = true;

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void closeDrawer() {
    xOffSet = 0;
    yOffSet = 0;
    scaleFactor = 1;
    isDrawerOpen = false;

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setDragging(bool input) {
    isDragging = input;

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Could you give me a hand on How I could solve this or provide some snippets that could help? I tried many things and nothing I tried worked, and I know I am missing something.
Any help will be really appreciated, thank you all in advance!